# what is the manifest yaml file equivalent of the create configmap --from-env-file command

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

I need to create a manifest configmap yaml file (configmap template helm) that execute the same operation that we get when we run the command

> kubectl create configmap config-env-file --from-env-file=config.properties

Please note that I must retrieve the parameters from 'properties' file (and not from configmap file)

config.properties file

```
# dummy param
node=2

pod=3
```

when i run the command that create the the configmap from the config.properties file, I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  node: "2"
  pod: "3"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-env-file
  namespace: default
```

I need to reproduce this result by building a configmap helm chart

thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?  Can you convert that `key=value` properties file to a `key: value` YAML file?

Comment: please see above

Comment: did the answer help you, btw?

Answer (score 0):

I am by far not an expert on templating, but this works (I took your example literally):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-env-file
  namespace: default
data:
{{- $content := .Files.Get "resources/config.properties" }}
{{- range $line := splitList "\n" $content }}
  {{ $parts := split "=" $line }}
  {{- $key := printf "%s" $parts._0  }}
  {{- $value := printf "%s" $parts._1 }}
  {{- printf "%s:" $key }} {{ quote $value }}
{{- end }}
```